# RegEx that will match all integers and X?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a field for which I am capturing pasted text.  I need to cleanse said pasted data so that it only includes 0-9 and X/x.  What kind of RegEx do I use in javascript to filter the pasted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.replace(/[^0-9xX]/g,"")` will remove all characters that are not 0-9, x or X.

[Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: just as a comment to this answer, it is possible to use: `/[^\dx]/gi`